# passing an array of structs from c# to C++ using com callable wrapper

Tags: c#, c++, com, marshalling

Consider the code below that is meant to be accessed by C++ using com

```
    namespace MarshalLib
    {
        //define an interface for account services
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [Guid("39B8A693-79BB-4638-92DE-245A88720953")]
        public interface IAccountStructLookup
        {
            AccountStruct RetrieveAccount(int acctId);
            void UpdateBalance(ref AccountStruct account);
            Alias[] GetRef();
        }

        //Implement an account struct
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [Guid("DB48C5B6-9646-491A-B030-C0CADCFC03E0")]
        public struct AccountStruct
        {
            public int AccountId;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
            public string AccountName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Currency)]
            public decimal Balance;

            //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 5)]
            //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)]
            //public Alias[] Aliases;
        }

        [ComVisible(true)]
        [Guid("9829CAB3-4020-47EA-BE72-86EC7CFFAE1D")]
        public struct Alias
        {
            public string Name;
        }
        //implement a class to provide account services
        //using an AccountStruct
        [ComVisible(true)]
        [Guid("CEFE5CAA-5C7E-464F-8020-E0FC78180D9B")]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        public class DniNetStructsObj : IAccountStructLookup
        {
            public AccountStruct RetrieveAccount(int acctId)
            {
                AccountStruct result = new AccountStruct();
                if (acctId == 123)
                {
                    result.AccountId = acctId;
                    result.AccountName = "myAccount";
                    result.Balance = 1009.95M;
                    //result.Aliases = new Alias[5];
                    //result.Aliases[0].Name = "1";
                    //result.Aliases[1].Name = "2";
                    //result.Aliases[2].Name = "3";
                    //result.Aliases[3].Name = "4";
                    //result.Aliases[4].Name = "5";

                }
                return result;
            }

            public void UpdateBalance(ref AccountStruct account)
            {
                //update the balance
                account.Balance += 500.00M;
            }
            public Alias[] GetRef( )
            {
                Alias[] al= new Alias[2];
                al[0].Name = "1";
                al[1].Name = "2";
                return al;
            }


}
```

And the C++ side of things

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "ConsoleApplication1.h"
#import "D:\Source Code\MarshalLib\MarshalLib\bin\Debug\MarshalLib.tlb" raw_interface_only

#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new DEBUG_NEW
#endif


// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;
using namespace MarshalLib;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    if (hModule != NULL)
    {
        // initialize MFC and print and error on failure
        if (!AfxWinInit(hModule, NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
        {
            // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
            _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed\n"));
            nRetCode = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
            CoInitialize(NULL);
            IAccountStructLookupPtr api(__uuidof(DniNetStructsObj));
            api->GetRef();
            CoUninitialize();
            }
            catch (...)
            {
            }

        }
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
        _tprintf(_T("Fatal Error: GetModuleHandle failed\n"));
        nRetCode = 1;
    }

    return nRetCode;
}
```

I get an error when I call api-GetRef() to get an array of structs. Please help me return an array of structs from c# and use it in c++.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well you are certainly not helping. I have tried many ways. If you dont know the answer then please dont bother commenting.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12484109/how-to-iterate-through-safearray

Comment: I'm just trying to elicit more information from you, so users will better understand what you're trying to accomplish and where exactly you are stuck. Also, there are far too many "give me teh codez" questions on [so], and most of them get ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with returning the array is that in the C++ you will see a pointer to struct and have no information about array size. You can try to marshal it as a SAFEARRAY, but IMO, SAFEARRAYs are pain in the neck.

I prefer to model it as this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("C3E38106-F303-46d9-9EFB-AD8A8CA8644E")]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    public int Value;

    // I marshal strings as arrays! see note at the bottom
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string Unit
}

[ComVisible(true),
Guid("BD4E6810-8E8C-460c-B771-E266B6F9122F"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)
]
public interface IMyService
{
    int GetData([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] out MyStruct[] data);
}
```

The client code is like this:

```
Lib::MyStruct* data;
long size = svc->GetData(&data);

for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
{
  Lib::MyStruct& current = data[i];
  long val = current.Value;
  bstr_t unit = current.Unit;
  // ...
}                                           

// now you need to release the memory. However, if you marshal
// strings in struct as BSTRs, you need to first release them by
// calling SysFreeString. This is why I prefer to marshal strings
// as arrays whenever I can: you can still easily construct a bstr_t
// in your client code, but you don't need to release them explicitly
CoTaskMemFree(data);
```

With regard to comment about `SAFEARRAY`s: they are required only if the interface must be automation compliant i.e. late-bound i.e. an `IDispatch` interface i.e. marked as `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch`. If this is not the case (and I declared the interface as custom i.e. `ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown`) using the standard arrays is perfectly fine and they are equally well supported as `SAFEARRAY`s. Furthermore, working with `SAFEARRAY`s of custom structs brings [some additional](http://vcfaq.mvps.org/com/4.htm) [complexity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9b968e9-2241-4d99-9e59-6ee0aeea5942%28VS.85%29) which I prefer to avoid. If you don't need late binding, there is no reason to fight with `SAFEARRAY`s.

With regard to `CComSafeArray`, as documented, it doesn't support `VT_RECORD` which is required to support arrays of structs (another option is to marshal it as `VT_VARIANT` with `IRecordInfo` but I won't even go into that).

Comment: I have tried LPArray it was giving out errors when the SizeConst is not equal to the size of the array. But I will give it a try once more.

Comment: That's exactly why I return the size as return value and avoid using method parameters.

Comment: I am always getting back size as 0. I have the CSharp (see above)

Comment: that's because your method returns `void` and not `int`. You must return the number of entries in the array.

Comment: By default, C# arrays are marshaled as SAFEARRAYs to COM, aren't they? And SAFEARRAYs are definitely the way to go for arrays, because other ways are not well-supported. Yes, they are awkward in C++, but that's not COM's or C#'s fault. Besides, you shouldn't use them with your bare hands, but with a wrapper like ATL's CComSafeArray.

Comment: I have modified the answer to explain why plain arrays are safe, and why CComSafeArray is not a good choice for arrays of UDTs.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to expose your managed code via an interface and register it using regasm and create type library (tlb file). Then you can use this in your unmanaged code.

Refer to this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/deeptanshuv/archive/2005/06/26/432870.aspx

Comment: Thanks, passing intrinsic types is trivial but try passing array of structures. Anyways I will do some reading tonight to hopefully wrap this up behind.